# Python date time field

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

See this program:

```
dfPeople = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['alice','bob'],'date_of_birth': ['10/25/1995 03:30','10/29/2002 9:25']})

dfPeople['date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(dfPeople['date_of_birth'])

dfPeople['date_of_birth'].dtype 

theDate = dfPeople['date_of_birth'].dt.date
```

theDate is supposed to extract the date. When I try something like this

```
if theDate[0]=='1995-10-25':
    print("equal")
```

I do not see the statement printed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is expected, because compare type `date` with type `string`.

So need:

```
from datetime import datetime

if theDate[0]==datetime.strptime('1995-10-25', '%Y-%m-%d').date():
     print("equal")
```

If want compare in pandas for mask is possible use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [`Series.dt.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) for remove times, but still datetimes, so compare with strings working:

```
theDate = dfPeople['date_of_birth'].dt.floor('d')
#alternative
#theDate = dfPeople['date_of_birth'].dt.normalize()
print (theDate == '1995-10-25')   
0     True
1    False
Name: date_of_birth, dtype: bool
```